# Ionic - [ui.router] can't navigate nested states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I've been trying to make this work, I think I'm missing something but I don't know what. I've tried with absolute paths and same problem. Perhaps the way I'm trying to link the states?

Tree view goes like this:

```
- app
  - app.category
    - app.category.category-detail
```

I can navigate from `app`, to `app.category` but I can't go any further, here are my routes:

```
        .state('app.category', {
            url: "/category?catId",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/category.html",
                    controller: "CategoryCtrl",
                    params: ['catId ']

                }

            }
        })
        .state('app.category.category-detail', {
            url: "/category-detail",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/category-detail.html",
                    controller: "DirectoryDetailCtrl",
                    params: [ 'catId' ]
                }
            }
        })
```

This is my **category.html**

```
<ion-view>

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark nav-title-slide-ios7 bg-nav" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear" ng-click="myGoBack()">
            <i class="ion-chevron-left blanco negrita"></i>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-content class="directory-content padding-3 bg-gris">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="category in categories" class="item-thumbnail-left tarjeta">
            <a ui-sref="app.category.category-detail">
                {{category.categoryName}}
            </a>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Now, if I inspect this website with Chrome Dev Tools I can see the next link is generated:

```
    <a ui-sref="app.category.category-detail" href="#/app/category/category-detail?catId=1" class="">
         Category 1
    </a>
```

But the view is not being loaded, and no error is shown.

**category-detail.html**

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark nav-title-slide-ios7 bg-nav" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear" ng-click="myGoBack()">
            <i class="ion-chevron-left blanco negrita"></i>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-content class="category-content padding-3 bg-gris">
        <h1>CATEGORY</h1>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one issue with params definition and second with view/target naming

I. *params: ['catId]* issue

Read more about **`params: {}`** object for example here:

#### [Angular ui router passing data between states without URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28248236/1679310)

Notation used above:

```
params: [ 'catId' ]
```

is not valid anymore... Now we have more settings arround, e.g. the default value:

```
params : { cateId : null }
```

read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28248236/1679310)

II. view naming

It also seems, that you are trying to target the same **`ui-view="menuContent"`** from `'app.category'` and its child state `'app.category.category-detail'` ... both with relative naming:

```
   .state('app.category', {
        url: "/category?catId",
        views: {
            'menuContent': { // no @ = relative name
             ...

    .state('app.category.category-detail', {
        url: "/category-detail",
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
            ...
```

In case, that this target **`ui-view="menuContent"`** is defined in the 'app' state, we have to use absolute naming

```
.state('app.category.category-detail', {
    url: "/category-detail",
    views: {
        'menuContent@app': {
        ...
```

The reason is, that name view notation without '@' is realtive and could be expressed as 'viewName@parentState'. So these are the same

```
.state('app.category', {
    url: "/category?catId",
    views: {
        // relative
        'menuContent': {
        // absolute - targeting the same ui-view
        'menuContent@app': { // this is absolute name
```

Try to get more here *(not about ionic, but the UI-Router stuff behind is the same)*:

- [Angularjs ui-router not reaching child controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27457460/1679310)
- [Angular UI Router - Nested States with multiple layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310)

Comment: Adding the absolute name and changing the `params` option worked, thank you Radim. I'll read more about the ui-router to prevent this errors appear again in the future :)

Comment: Great to see that Ariel, really. Enjoy mighty UI-Router ;)