# AngularJS UI-Router multiple views - load only in a view

Tags: angularjs, nested, state, angular-ui-router

In AngularJS, how to load only a particular named view? For example, in below code, if contact is selected, I like it to load only in bottomview and keeping rest of the views (say topview) as it is. Unfortunately, AngularJS is loading all the views. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        'topview': {templateUrl: 'top.html'},
        'bottomview': {templateUrl: 'bottom.html'}
    }
})

.state('contact', {
    url: '/contact',
    views: {
        'bottomview': {templateUrl: 'contact.html'}
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is good, and could be achieved with state nesting:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        'topview': {templateUrl: 'top.html'},
        'bottomview': {templateUrl: 'bottom.html'}
    }
})

.state('home.contact', {
    url: '/contact',
    views: {
        'bottomview@': {templateUrl: 'contact.html'}
    }
})
```

So, 'contact' is now child state of 'home', and it means, that

- all views loaded by parent ('home')
- and not replaced by child ('contact')

are not reloaded when `contact` is selected.

*Note, that in case, that we target bottomView of the index.html, we need to use **view absolute naming** - `'bottomview@'`, e.g. check more details here [Angularjs ui-router not reaching child controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27457460/1679310)*

Comment: Great to see that, really! Enjoy mighty UI-Router ;)