# UI-Router abstract state child doesnt render

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I'm having some difficulties to understand how UI-Router abstract state work.
Here's the thing :
I have an index.html with only a `<ui-view>` tag inside its `<body>`.

There is two main states : Landing and App ( /landing and /app ).

No problem with the landing state for now, because its only a static file ( no child view etc ).

But for my /app state, I need an abstract parent state that cover the whole application ( need to resolve User Profile for each child states ).

The thing is that child of this abstract state also have sub-view. And I can't make those render.

My $stateProvider config (simplified) :

```
//landing state, no problem here
.state('landing', {
    url: '/landing',
    templateUrl: 'landing.html'
})
// my abstract parent state, with the resolve
.state('root', {
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    template: "<div ui-view></div>",
    resolve: {
        current_user: function (UserFactory) {
            return UserFactory.initCurrentUserProfile();
        }
    }
})

// the child which cannot render the view headerAndSearchbar
.state('root.app', {
    url: '/app',
    templateUrl: 'app.html',
    views: {
        'headerAndSearchbar': {
            templateUrl: './partials/header/headerAndSearchbar.html'
        }
    }
})
```

app.html :

```
<div ui-view="headerAndSearchbar">     
</div>
<div>
    This is app.html     
</div>
```

Note that if i remove **views** declaration in the state root.app, i can see the text "This is app.html".
headerAndSearchbar.html only contains simple html & css

Any ideas ?  I'm bashing my head on this- What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues.

Firstly, There are in fact two views, inside of the child `'root.app'`.

1. Unnamed (the one, which is related to templateUrl 'app.html')
2. named view 'headerAndSearchbar'

And that means, that both most be declared inside of the **`views : {}`** setting:

```
.state('root.app', {
    url: '/app',
    //templateUrl: 'app.html',
    views: {
        '' : { templateUrl: 'app.html' },
        'headerAndSearchbar': { ... n
    }...
```

But that is not enough.

Secondly, we need **absolute naming** for the second (named) because it is not related to its parent, but to itself:

```
.state('root.app', {
    url: '/app',
    //templateUrl: 'app.html',
    views: {
        '' : { templateUrl: 'app.html' },
        // this is the same as a path to parent view 'headerAndSearchbar@root'
        // 'headerAndSearchbar': { ...
        // this means ... search in this state, inside of app.html
        'headerAndSearchbar@root.app': { ... 
    }...
```

Check these for more details:

- [Angularjs ui-router not reaching child controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27457460/1679310)
- [Angular UI Router - Nested States with multiple layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310)