# UI router child views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I am building an angularJS app. My pages contain a header, content and footer. Header and Footer are consistent for all the pages. Currently I have placed the header and footer in the `index.html` file and I am using `ui-view` to change the content each time the user navigates to a partial view. This works fine, but I want to implement the header and footer as separate views.

This is what I have so far. I don't get any errors, but I don't see the content being rendered from `header.html` and `footer.html`.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        url: '/main',
        views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl: 'header/header.html'
                },
                'footer': {
                    templateUrl: 'footer/footer.html'
                },
         },
    })

    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        parent: 'main',
        views: {
            'view': {
                templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
                controller: 'loginCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'login'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('reset-password', {
        url: '/reset-password',
        parent: 'main',
        views: {
            'view': {
                templateUrl: 'views/resetPassword.html'
            }
        }
    })
```

I want all the child states of `main` to contain the content in `header.html` and `footer.html`

Comment: can you post your HTML too? maybe the problem is there

Comment: Could you post your index.html content?

Comment: This could be useful: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#example---name-matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [fully working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UEzSeBCtWtdP6WJv9JhX?p=preview)

There are more details:

#### [Angularjs ui-router not reaching child controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27457460/1679310)

In case, that the `index.html` looks like this:

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="view"></div>
<div ui-view="footer"></div>
```

We need to use absolute naming for sub-states:

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    parent: 'main',
    views: {
        //'view': {
        'view@': {
            templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'login'
        }
    }
})

.state('reset-password', {
    url: '/reset-password',
    parent: 'main',
    views: {
        //'view@': {
        'view@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/resetPassword.html'
        }
    }
})
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UEzSeBCtWtdP6WJv9JhX?p=preview)