# Angular ui-router resolve inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to create an abstract parent state, that has only one job: to resolve the current user through an ajax server call, and then pass this object to the child state. The problem is that the child state never gets loaded. Please have a look at this plunker: [Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wq2S9s)

a `state`

```
angular.module('test', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    // Parent route
    $stateProvider.state('main', {
      abstract:true,
      resolve: {
        user: function(UserService){
          return UserService.getUser();
        }
      }
    });

    // Child route
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
      parent: 'main',
      url: '/',
      controller: 'HomeController',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      template: '<h1>{{$ctrl.user.name}}</h1>'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  });
```

a `factory`

```
angular.module('test').factory('UserService', function($q){
  function getUser() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // Immediately resolve it
    deferred.resolve({
      name: 'Anonymous'
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return {
    getUser: getUser
  };
});
```

a `controller`

```
angular.module('test').controller('HomeController', function(user){
  this.user = user;
});
```

In this example, the `home` state will never display the template, I don't really understand why. If I remove the `parent: 'main'` line, then it displays the template, but of course I get an error because it cannot find the `user` dependency in the `HomeController`.

What am I missing? I did everything like it is described in ui-router's documentation, I think this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every parent must have a target ui-view in *template* for its child

```
$stateProvider.state('main', {
  abstract:true,
  resolve: {
    user: function(UserService){
      return UserService.getUser();
    }
  }
  template: '<div ui-view=""></div>'
});
```

*NOTE: Another option is to use absolute names and target index.html .. but in this case the above is the way to go ([Angularjs ui-router not reaching child controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27457460/1679310))*